# Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, language, user-interface, language-pack

I had Windows 7 Ultimate before I upgraded to Windows 8 Pro and before, in Windows Update, there were updates that allowed me to install more language packs for Windows. After installing the updates I would have more languages for the interface.

Now I don't see any language updates, is it not possible to have various languages in Windows 8? Or maybe they are not ready yet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible, and now it's not restricted to some editions but available for everyone ;). As you state in Windows 7 they appeared as optional updates in Windows Update but only for Ultimate and Enterprise editions if I'm not mistaken. Now they can be installed from the control panel, it's in the "Clock, Language and Region" section.

These steps should get you settled:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to search for settings and type "add a language", open it (or go to the control panel and select "Add a language").

   [image: Searching for it]
2. Click "Add a language", select the one you'd like to have the UI in and add it.
3. At this point, if your Internet connection is fast enough you can already see if there is an available LIP (Language Interface Pack) in that language or not:

   [image: Installing a new LIP]
4. Select it from the list and go to its options. Wait for it to check if there is a LIP available in that language, if there is not there's nothing you can do unfortunately.
5. Assuming there is, click in "Download and install language pack":

   [image]
6. After that you're set, if you wish to select that language as your primary one move it to the top of the list or click "Make this the primary language" in its options.
7. Log off and back on again after you made it your primary language and you can use it already.

Note that installed language packs are system wide, so if more users want to use them they don't have to be downloaded and installed again.

Comment: I got it installed and after a reboot the language is changed, thanks.

Comment: You don't have to reboot, logging off and on again having changed the language you want to use is enough. I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but I am currently trying to do this in Windows 8, and although the language pack downloads, I get an "installation failed" every single time. Is this a known issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, it's worked for me anytime I tried. Do you see an error code when the message is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

There are already languages pre-installed into Windows 8. If you would like to access them here is how:

1. Open the Charms Bar by hovering over the top right corner.
2. Click **Search**.
3. Click **Settings**.
4. Search for `Language`.
5. Click **Add a language**.
6. Now choose whichever language you want by scrolling down or by typing in your language into the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

To add a language:

1. Navigate to `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language` (you can copy and paste that in the address bar in the window that opens with <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Click "Add a language"