# Can I change the Windows 8 Pro language after buying a PC?

Tags: windows-8, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)

I want to buy a laptop with Windows 8 Pro.

Can I then install another language in this edition of Windows?

And if yes, can you please provide additional information about how to change language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes you can](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/language#1TC=t1)! This represents a change from Windows 7.

You can change the language by

1. From the charm search bar search `language` and choose `Settings`
2. In the Language Control Panel, tap or click `Add a language`
3. To make it a display language move the panel to the top of the list. For example, move the spanish panel on top of the English panel.

[See the official kb.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607)

[image]

--edit--
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions) says these features should be available in all versions; with the exception of exotic Chinese only versions.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. But I need to change not INPUT language, but WHOLE OS Language

Comment: @Pleerock its called windows display language.

Comment: This is correct - I have just replaced US Windows with UK Windows by doing exactly this.

Comment: And what about OS version? Is it possible to change in Windows 8 Pro Edition? (because I know in windows 7 I can't change display language in starter, home and pro editions)