# Can I change the system language on a Windows 8 computer from English to Russian?

Tags: windows-8, language, language-pack

I have an HP laptop computer running Windows 8.  It was purchased in the US and is in English.  I need to use it in Russia and have the entire system language be Russian.  Can I change this myself or do I need to purchase Windows 8 in Russian and install that on the laptop?

Comment: @Karan: Good catch.  Voting to close.

Comment: @DragonLord: Actually, a simple search resulted in http://superuser.com/questions/499457, http://superuser.com/questions/502095, http://superuser.com/questions/509282, http://superuser.com/questions/509317 and likely others I missed, all of which have been closed as dupes of the one I linked to above.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Windows Vista and Windows 7, where language packs require the Enterprise or Ultimate editions, you can [install and use language packs in any edition of Windows 8 as well as in Windows RT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607).

On the **Start** screen, search for "**language**" and select **Language** under **Settings**. Click **Add a language**, then select the language you want to add.  Select **Options** on the language just added, then click **Download and install language pack**.  Move the new language to the top of the list, and re-login to apply the change.