# How to install language packs in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, language-pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)

I'm now in Windows 7 Ultimate and I see different language pack updates in Windows Update, but in another computer I upgraded to Windows 8 Pro and there is no language pack update.

How can I install more language packs in Windows 8?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, Cecil see my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/497989/18050

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, search for language:

[image]

Then select “Add a language”:

[image]

In the dialog that appears you can now click the “Add a language” button to add a new language:

[image]

There are plenty to choose from and they are automatically downloaded (and I presume thus no longer distributed via Windows Update as an optional update):

[image]