# How do I add handwriting support for non-English languages?

Tags: windows-8, handwriting-recognition

I'd like to use the handwriting recognition features for Japanese.

Currently only English is available:
[image: Touch Keyboard English][image: Touch Keyboard Japanese]
*As seen from the Touch Keyboard
(`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\tabtip.exe`)*

This is what I get after enumerating through [InkRecognizer.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkrecognizer.name.aspx) on my system:
[image: InkRecognizers]

Windows 8 Pro, English. Added Japanese (Microsoft IME) keyboard.

Comment: OK, you say you added a Japanese Keyboard, but did you actually [add it as a Language](http://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)?

Comment: @techie007 No, I assumed that was for changing the display language. I can try that, but do you know if language packs are uninstallable?

Comment: From MS: [Windows 8 language packs are available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607), it includes a section entitled "How to uninstall a Windows 8 language pack", so yes you can uninstall them. :)

Comment: @techie007 This looks like the answer. Didn't even need to restart.

Comment: Nice, I'll throw it in as an answer.

Comment: @techie007 [Not so nice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314818/is-it-possible-to-use-japanese-handwriting-recognition-without-installing-the-la) :(

Comment: Re your SO question: the users are going to need the language pack installed to use the OS-supported language features.  The "Engine" you speak of is in that language pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you added a Japanese Keyboard, but you'll have to actually add it as a Language.

Info on adding them can be found in this SU question: [Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)

And here on Microsoft's site: [Windows 8 language packs are available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2607607)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 introduces fair degree of compartmentalizing to this topic. It still has the option to download language packs to completely convert your system to another language, but now let's you choose Handwriting alone, as well as Speech alone.

It's not there for the language I want, but the UI implies it's there for some:
[image]
Search for **Edit language and keyboard options**, click on a language and then **Options**.

Answer (score 0):

How to use IME Pad in Win8, READ:

Well, I only know how to use the old IME Pad we used to use in Win 7

To able to have the handwriting feature (IME Pad)for Chinese or whatever countries in Window 8, you DO NOT have to download anything.

Go to control panel, languages,

On the left hand side bar, press ' Advanced Setting'

Scroll down and you will see 'Switching input method'

Tick the box ' Use the desktop language bar when it's avaliable'

And it asks you to log off,

After the bar shows up, it looks the same as the old window,

Choose Chinese (Taiwan), Tool menu, IME Pad (Don't forget to switch it to Chinese from English before choosing the IME Pad)

Thats it.

Hope I can help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after updating Windows 8 to Windows 8.1.
How I fixed it was download and install the language pack

Do this
1) Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings
In the first option for Windows display language, choose Use language list (recommended).
2) Then, go to Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language
Click options for the language you want and you should see a link that says "Download and install language pack". Do this and handwriting should be back after this installation is completed. This installation (excluding download) about 30 minutes on Core i5 my laptop for simplified chinese.