# How to change the default language in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have several languages in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/497982/is-it-possible-to-have-several-languages-in-windows-8)

Is it possible to change the language of my Windows 8 installation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the language pack from Windows Update. In Windows 8 you can do this in all editions, in 7 only in Ultimate i believe.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Regional_restrictions_and_variations)